# find leading zeros: performance

Tags: python-3.x, random

I am trying to find a N number of leading zeros from the output of the sha1 hash function. I would like N to go up to 10 or 9. Currently I can get to 7 in about 7 minutes (even though is not always that fast), but already 8 takes forever. The input to the sha1 must be a combination between an input_str and a random generated string.

Here is my code:

```
import os
import base64
import hashlib
import time

def gen_keys_06(_urandom=os.urandom, _encode=base64.b64encode):
    while True:
        yield _encode(_urandom(4)).decode('ascii')

def search_matching_random_str(input_str, zeroes, _sha1=hashlib.sha1):
    leading_zeros = "0"*zeroes
    for my_random_str in gen_keys_06():
        input_str_my_random_str = "".join([input_str, my_random_str])
        hashval = _sha1(input_str_my_random_str.encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()
        if hashval[:zeroes] == leading_zeros:
            return hashval, my_random_str

def get_time(input_data, zeroes):
    start = time.perf_counter()
    val, random_str = search_matching_random_str(input_data, zeroes)
    print(f'hash: {val}')
    print(f'random_str: {random_str}')
    finish = time.perf_counter()
    print(f'Finished in {round(finish-start, 2)} seconds(s)')


if __name__ == '__main__':

    first_str = "eTSlASZYlLNgKJuYeIQvGVbiAcLEEOVgAQPzSrtCOIwQxQHyFHcfjgRQJBJDlojx"
    get_time(first_str, 4)
```

On what should I work to make it faster?

Comment: @Manuel see the EDIT, try to change the value in `get_time` function up to 10. How long does it take?

Comment: Have you tried [profiling](https://docs.python.org/3/library/profile.html)?

Comment: Are you trying to mine crypto? Thought the point of mining was to be slow.

Comment: Your random string doesn't look fully random to me. It seems to always end with `==`. Is that a requirement somehow? And does it really need to be a random *string*, not random *bytes*? And does it really need to be *random*?

Comment: No it is not a requirement. Can also be random bytes. The point is to find a random bytes/string that has more entropy (for that I try to include upper, lower, digits and punctuation). The `==` can be cut by slicing, no improvement though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- `zeros` or `zeroes`? Better make up your mind and stick with one.
- `str.join` is good when you want to join an iterable. For two strings, just use `+`.
- Instead of always reencoding and rehashing the input string, you can do it *once* and then *copy* the resulting hasher (state) for different extensions.
- Instead of creating random bytes and then elaborately turning them into a string and back to bytes, just use the bytes. Since that's also just a single function call, you can ditch your `gen_keys_06` and its overhead.
- `str.startswith` is at least simpler, don't know about speed.
- For measuring performance, create a benchmark that runs the function much more than just once, as a single time is rather random. Or change the function so it tries a fixed number of random extensions (let's say a million) instead of stopping at the first successful one.
- You ask us *"On what should I work to make it faster?"*. That's a question to ask a [profiler](https://docs.python.org/3/library/profile.html).
- Producing random values takes time. Check the profiler's results (or leave out the randomness when doing the million-extensions thing) to see whether it's significant here. If it is, maybe try a different randomness source (I think I've seen someone say that `os.urandom` is slow on Linux). Or if you don't actually need randomness, try increasing bytes instead.
- Do you really want zero-*nibbles*? Or would zero-*bytes* work as well, i.e., are you maybe really only interested in even numbers of zero-nibbles? Then you could use `digest` instead of `hexdigest`, which is probably faster because bytes are probably what the hasher actually works with and because it makes digests half as large and you'd check for fewer zeros.

A version incorporating some of those points:

```
def search_matching_random_str(input_str, zeros, _sha1=hashlib.sha1, _urandom=os.urandom):
    leading_zeros = "0" * zeros
    hasher_copy = _sha1(input_str.encode()).copy
    while True:
        my_random_bytes = _urandom(4)
        hasher = hasher_copy()
        hasher.update(my_random_bytes)
        hashval = hasher.hexdigest()
        if hashval.startswith(leading_zeros):
            return hashval, my_random_bytes
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for you comments. I think the last is a very good point. Working with bytes, end so `digest` would make it faster. So I will go that way